# Can this string of inequalities take on arbitrary values?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a,b,c,d)$ be a 4-tuple of real numbers such that $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$, but is otherwise arbitrary. Are there real sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$, such that lim inf $x_n$ $+$ lim inf $y_n$ $= a$, lim inf $(x_n + y_n) = b$, lim sup $(x_n + y_n) = c$, and lim sup $x_n$ $+$ lim sup $y_n$ $= d$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $a=0$, then we may add a constant to $x_i$ and subtract it from $y_i$ to achieve $\liminf x_n=\liminf y_n=0$; this does not affect $b$, $c$, and $d$. Without loss of generality, assume that $\limsup x_n\geq d/2$; then $c\geq d/2$ as well.

Similarly, since $\limsup y_n\leq d/2$, we get $b\leq d/2$.

Conversely, it seems that any 4-tuple with $b\leq (a+d)/2\leq c$ is reachable. Set $\liminf x_n=\liminf y_n=a/2$,  $\limsup x_n=\limsup y_n=d/2$, achieved on sparse pairwise  disjoint sequences of indices. Now it is easy to reach $b$ and $c$.